# Standard error of components of coefficient estimate in linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, standard-deviation, standard-error

As I understand it, $\text{standard error} = \frac{\text{standard deviation}}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $n$ is the number of observations. I also know that $cov(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^{2}(X^{T}X)^{-1}$; this is a pxp variance-covariance matrix. So why is the standard error of the components of the coefficient estimate vector $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}$ in, for example, a normal linear model, $\sigma^{2}[(X^{T}X)^{-1}]_{ii}$ and not $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sigma^{2}[(X^{T}X)^{-1}]_{ii}$ where the subscript $ii$ denotes the $i,i$th entry of the matrix?

Comment: i asked a related question yesterday, using R... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262160/relationship-between-point-estimation-and-confidence-interval

Comment: The "$n$" factor is implicit already: consider the case where $X$ has been [whitened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation), so $X^TX=nI$.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Hmm, yes, I can see when it is whitened it works but I can't generalise it -  could you elaborate on where it is implicit?

Comment: It's just dot products vs. covariances (sums vs. averages): $\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{y} = \overline{(xy)}\times{n}$

Comment: @GeoMatt22 I'm afraid I don't find it any easier to understand using the equality you presented. :l Could you provide working?

Comment: I wrote an answer that tries to clarify. Let me know if things are still unclear!

Answer (score 1):

The "$n$" factor is implicit already in $\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X}$.

This is easiest to see in the case where $\boldsymbol{X}$ has been [whitened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation), so $\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X}=n\boldsymbol{I}$.

More generally we have $\boldsymbol{X}=[\boldsymbol{x}_1,\ldots\boldsymbol{x}_p]$, where $\boldsymbol{x}_p\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the entries of the matrix are
$$\left(\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X}\right)_{ij}=\boldsymbol{x}_i^T\boldsymbol{x}_j$$
Now choose a pair of columns, $\boldsymbol{a}=\boldsymbol{x}_i$ and $\boldsymbol{b}=\boldsymbol{x}_j$. Then we have
$$\boldsymbol{a}^T\boldsymbol{b}=\sum_{k=1}^na_kb_k=\overline{(ab)}\,n$$
So each entry of the matrix is a dot product, which can be seen as $n$ times an average.

In the case where $\boldsymbol{X}$ has been centered so the columns have zero means, the product-matrix entries are *covariances*.

For an overview of the general case, see [**here**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44838/how-are-the-standard-errors-of-coefficients-calculated-in-a-regression).